# Unpredictable z-index in Titanium

Tags: titanium, z-index, appcelerator

this strange bug has been bugging me for two straight days!

I have 5 views each containing a scroll view and set z-index on them as they're clicked. For some odd reason, the one with z-index of 3 always shows on top of the one with z-index of 4, except when it is the second to the last element was clicked. Just what is going on?!

Please check out the code below. I'm using Alloy. Obviously not production code, but I realized that it might not be my code so I tested it with the following code. Thank you so much for the help!

The Alloy markup:

```
<!-- index.xml -->
<Alloy>
  <Window id="container">
    <View id="v0" class="test" top="0">
      <ScrollView borderColor="green">
        <Label/>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    <View id="v1" class="test" top="40">
      <ScrollView borderColor="blue">
        <Label/>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    <View id="v2" class="test" top="80">
      <ScrollView borderColor="red">
        <Label/>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    <View id="v3" class="test" top="120">
      <ScrollView borderColor="purple">
        <Label/>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
    <View id="v4" class="test" top="160">
      <ScrollView borderColor="teal">
        <Label/>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Here's the main script:

```
// index.js
zs = [];

changeOrder = function(){
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    z = zs[i];
    v = $["v#{i}"];
    // Set the supposedly correct order of view stack
    v.setZIndex(z);
    // Display the order for debugging
    v.children[0].children[0].setText(z);
};

$.v0.addEventListener("click", function(){
  zs = [5,4,3,0,1];
  changeOrder();
});

$.v1.addEventListener("click", function(){
  zs = [1,5,4,3,0];
  changeOrder();
});

$.v2.addEventListener("click", function(){
  zs = [0,1,5,4,3];
  changeOrder();
});

$.v3.addEventListener("click", function(){
  zs = [3,0,1,5,4];
  changeOrder();
});

$.v4.addEventListener("click", function(){
  zs = [4,3,0,1,5];
  changeOrder();
});

$.container.open()
```

Ti mobile 3.0.22 Alloy 1.0.0 iOS Simulator 6.1 OSX 10.8

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing PHP with javascript, so the reference to the view element is faulty.  Also, the way you have the views setup is faulty, so when you click the topmost view, the others become unclickable, but, this does what you're trying to do. This:

```
v = $["v#{i}"];
```

Should be:

v = $["v"+i];

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad! I program in CoffeeScript and I manually converted the code to JavaScript for the post. It should have the same effect as described as the references seem to be valid when run.

Comment: No prob, I have confirmed that it does indeed work with the above fix.

Comment: Thanks for trying the code out! When you say it does work you mean the z-index works as expected or the problem is indeed there? Given my ego, I would love to know if it's my fault or Appcelerator's. ;P

Comment: Your logic is all solid, likely the culprit something is lost in translation between coffeescript and javascript

Comment: Update: I believe it's a bug in Titanium now that someone at Appcelerator's JIRA opened the issue and indicated it as an Titanium-on-iOS bug. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-2033